# iOS: When opening a URL in safari, is it somehow possible to send authorization token in header field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, safari

I am trying to look for a way to open a URL in safari with a header field that contains an authorization key.

Currently, the string looks something like this when opening a URL. `"https://www.myWebsite/user?token=\(userToken)"`

However,  I want to put the token in a header field for better security reasons. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not secure in header and in URL anyway, because you are using unsecure  http protocol.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the questions. It is using a secure HTTP protocol.

Comment: Any way what is the problem using token in URL? Are you afraid that user will copy it? You can use one time request token: it will become invalid after first request.